# ODBC Connection Information Export script from Windows XP to Windows 7?

Tags: vbscript, odbc, export

Looking for an ODBC connection information script that exports from a WinXP box to a Windows 7 box.

Answer (score 0):

You can export ODBC setting from registry and restore it on other machine. Don't know if there is script that can do it, but it should be easy. Be aware, because more and more Windows machines are 64 bit versions and there registry location differs for 32 and 64 bit applications. Have a look at: https://serverfault.com/questions/239002/registry-for-odbcad32-on-window-server-2003-64-bit/240112#240112

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the registry information may point to a driver dll that does not exist in the same place on Windows 7 x64. For instance, on XP the drive may be located in "C:\Program Files\" while in Win7 x64 it's located under "C:\Program Files (x86)" - just wanted to point that to those that stumble upon this.

vbscript I put together:

```
objShell.Run "reg export " & Chr(34) & "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC" & Chr(34) & "SystemODBC64.reg",1,True
objShell.Run "reg export " & Chr(34) & "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ODBC" & Chr(34) & "UserODBC64.reg",1,True
```

And then, to update the script to merge into the 32-bit registry:

```
Set objOFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("SystemODBC64.reg", ForReading, False, TristateTrue)
strSystemReg64Contents = objOFile.ReadAll

WScript.Echo "Formatting system ODBC to 32-bit"
strSystemReg64 = Replace(strSystemReg64Contents, "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software","HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node",1,-1,1)

WScript.Echo "Creating System ODBC File"
objFSO.CreateTextFile("SystemODBC32.reg", True, True ).Write strSystemReg64

strUserReg64 = "UserODBC64.reg"
Set objOFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strUserReg64, ForReading, False, TristateTrue )
strUserReg64Contents = objOFile.ReadAll

WScript.Echo "Formatting user ODBC to 32-bit"
strUserReg64 = Replace(strUserReg64Contents, "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software","HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node",1,-1,1) 

WScript.Echo "Creating User ODBC File"
objFSO.CreateTextFile("UserODBC32.reg", True, True ).Write strUserReg64
```